# Imported Twig macro displays nothing i.e. not working

Tags: php, macros, twig

I'm trying to implement some sort of macro autoloading.

The idea is to define a bunch of macros and use them on all the next template files.

Here's how I'm trying to do it:

```php
<?php
    define('ROOT_FRONT', '/path/to/files/');
    define('LAYOUT_DIR', ROOT_FRONT . 'layout/');

    include(ROOT_FRONT . 'lib/Twig/Autoloader.php');
    Twig_Autoloader::register();
    
    $twig_loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(array(LAYOUT_DIR, ROOT_FRONT));
    
    $twig = new Twig_Environment($twig_loader, array(
        'charset' => 'ISO-8859-15',
        'debug' => !!preg_match('@\.int$@', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']),
        'cache' => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/cache/twig/'
    ));
    
    $macro_code = '';
    foreach(array_filter(
        array_diff(
            scandir(LAYOUT_DIR . 'macros/'),
            array('..','.')
        ),
        function($file)
        {
            return strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) == 'twig'
                && is_file(LAYOUT_DIR . 'macros/' . $file);
        }
    ) as $file)
    {
        $info = pathinfo($file);
        $macro_code .= '{% import \'macros/' . $info['basename'] . '\' as macros_' . $info['filename'] . ' %}';
    }
    
    $twig
        ->createTemplate($macro_code)
        ->render(array());
    
    $twig->display('index.twig', array());
```

If I have a file, say, `macro/clearfix.twig`, it will generate this template code, inside `$macro_code`:

```twig
{% import 'macros/clearfix' as macros_clearfix %}
```

The code inside `macro/clearfix.twig` is something like this:

```twig
{% macro clearfix(index, columns) %}

    {% if index is divisible by(columns) %}
        <div class="clearfix visible-md-block visible-lg-block"></div>
    {% endif %}
    
    {% if index is even %}
        <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
    {% endif %}
    
{% endmacro %}
```

And then, inside the `index.twig`, I have this:

```twig
{{ macros_clearfix.clearfix(index=2, columns=6) }}
```

But nothing is displayed.

However, the following code works:

```twig
{% set index = 2 %}
{% set columns = 6 %}

{% if index is divisible by(columns) %}
    <div class="clearfix visible-md-block visible-lg-block"></div>
{% endif %}

{% if index is even %}
    <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
{% endif %}
```

---

What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Am I misunderstanding something or applying this incorrectly?

Comment: You're passing the arguments strangely, you should pass them like: `{{ macros_clearfix.clearfix(2, 6) }}`

Comment: I know, but both means exactly the same. Since (honestly) the name of the macro is trash, I'm passing them like that. So I can know what means what, without reading the macro.

Comment: Why do you use this complex macro system while you can just add twig function to do that? Macro are not meant to be used globally on a project. Twig function are meant to do content generation AND to be registered globally

Comment: @goto I'm writting something based on that. In fact, I'm writting an answer and showing some code for this.

Comment: Possibly related question and answer - [Is it possible to make global macros in Twig 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71935376/is-it-possible-to-make-global-macros-in-twig-3)

Comment: @DarkBee Back in 2017, there was no Twig 3.

Comment: Can't see how that is relevant? I've provided a link to the other question because if future people arrive on this question I sure hope they don't use twig 2.0 anymore, which was put to EOL in december 2023

Comment: @DarkBee It's relevant because this question was about Twig 1 and (as a side effect) 2. Just because these versions are EOL doesn't mean this question is a duplicate or that the linked question answers this one. It doesn't. That's like going to a PHP 5.3 question and saying that the new thing introduced in 8.3 answers the question: it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

Twig **requires** you to load the macros inside the file where they will be used.
Just create custom functions to do what you want.

---

Twig (at least v1.30) doesn't implement macro inheritance.
This requires that you load **every** single macro you want to use on **every single file**.

The only way to do this is with functions, entirelly written in PHP.

This is what I've settled with:

- index.php:

  ```
  <?php
      define('ROOT_FRONT', '/path/to/files/');
      define('LAYOUT_DIR', ROOT_FRONT . 'layout/');

      include(ROOT_FRONT . 'lib/Twig/Autoloader.php');
      Twig_Autoloader::register();

      $twig_loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(array(LAYOUT_DIR, ROOT_FRONT));

      $twig = new Twig_Environment($twig_loader, array(
          'charset' => 'ISO-8859-15',
          'debug' => !!preg_match('@\.int$@', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']),
          'cache' => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/cache/twig/'
      ));

      // ~ magic happens here ~
      foreach(include(LAYOUT_DIR . 'fn.php') as $k => $fn)
      {
          $twig->addFunction(new Twig_SimpleFunction("fn_$k", $fn));
      }

      $twig->display('index.twig', array());
  ```
- fn.php:

  ```
  <?php
      return array(
          'clearfix' => function($index, $columns){
              $html = '';

              if(!($index % $columns))
              {
                  $html .= '<div class="clearfix visible-md-block visible-lg-block"></div>';
              }

              if(!($index & 1))
              {
                  $html .= '<div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>';
              }

              return $html;
          }
      );
  ```
- index.twig:

  ```
  {{ fn_clearfix(index=2, columns=6) }}
  ```

This way, all your code is neatly indexed, new functions are created automatically and it is pretty easy to extend it to your liking.

Probably this is the worst idea, but it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

> ### Macros
>
> As of Twig 2.0, macros imported in a file are not available in child templates anymore (via an include call for instance). You need to import macros explicitly in each file where you are using them.

From https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/deprecated.html