# Is it possible to make global macros in Twig 3?

Tags: php, twig

I want to upgrade my Twig from very old version (**2.x** or even **1.x**) to **3.3**. In old version macros imported in top level template are available in all extened and included templates. And I have a bunch of templates where I need my macros (100+ and many `embed` blocks). I **don't want to** import macros manually in evety template.

So, according to similar question [Twig auto import macros by environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52855116/twig-auto-import-macros-by-environment) I tried to implement suggested solution, but it doesn't work.
Actually I tried this:

```php
$tpl = $this->Twig->load('inc/function.twig');
$this->Twig->addGlobal('fnc', $tpl);
```

I also tried this:

```php
$tpl = $this->Twig->load('inc/function.twig');
$this->Twig->addGlobal('fnc', $tpl->unwrap());
```

but I have same result. In templates `fnc` is defined but it's a Template object and I can not access macros. I get a fatal error when I try to do it:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Twig\Error\RuntimeError: Accessing \Twig\Template attributes is forbidden
```

As I understand, in Twig 3 you can not just include macros using `addGlobal`.

Old Twig was added to our repository (was not ignored) and we probably will add to repository new Twig too, so it's possible to modify Twig's source code.

**UPD:**
When I try just to `addGlobal` my template with macros I get

```
Fatal error: Uncaught LogicException: Unable to add global "fnc" as the runtime or the extensions have already been initialized.
```

I've solved this problem using [this solution](https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/issues/3715#issuecomment-999616605) (I've extended `Environment` class).

Comment: Do you get an error when trying to access a method from the macro?

Comment: @DarkBee Yes, I get a fatal error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Twig\Error\RuntimeError: Accessing \Twig\Template attributes is forbidden`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During some testing I found out you can still call the "functions" defined inside a macro with pure `PHP`

```
<?php
    $wrapper = $twig->load('macro.html');
    $template = $wrapper->unwrap();
    echo $template->macro_Foo().''; //return a \Twig\Markup
```

With this in place you could write a wrapper around the macro and try to auto load them in a container.

---

First off we need an extension to enable and access the container

```
<?php
    class MacroWrapperExtension extends \Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension
    {
        public function getFunctions()
        {
            return [
                new \Twig\TwigFunction('macro', [$this, 'macro'], ['needs_environment' => true,]),
            ];
        }

        protected $container = null;

        public function macro(\Twig\Environment $twig, $template) {
            return $this->getContainer($twig)->get($template);
        }

        private function getContainer(\Twig\Environment $twig) {
            if ($this->container === null) $this->container = new MacroWrapperContainer($twig);
            return $this->container;
        }

    }
```

Next the container itself. The container is responsible to load and store/save the (auto loaded) macros in the memory. The code will try to locate and load any file in the map macros in your view folder.

```
template
|--- index.html
|--- macros
|------- test.html
|
```

```
<?php
    class MacroWrapperContainer {
        const FOLDER = 'macros';

        protected $twig = null;
        protected $macros = [];

        public function __construct(\Twig\Environment $twig) {
            $this->setTwig($twig)
                 ->load();
        }

        public function get($macro) {
            return $this->macros[$macro] ?? null;
        }

        protected function load() {
            foreach($this->getTwig()->getLoader()->getPaths() as $path) {
                if (!is_dir($path.'/'.self::FOLDER))  continue;
                $this->loadMacros($path.'/'.self::FOLDER);
            }
        }

        protected function loadMacros($path) {
            $files = scandir($path);
            foreach($files as $file) if ($this->isTemplate($file)) $this->loadMacro($file);
        }

        protected function loadMacro($file) {
            $name = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            if (!isset($this->macros[$name])) $this->macros[$name] = new MacroWrapper($this->getTwig()->load(self::FOLDER.'/'.$file));
        }

        protected function isTemplate($file) {
            return in_array(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), [ 'html', 'twig', ]);
        }

        protected function setTwig(\Twig\Environment $twig) {
            $this->twig = $twig;
            return $this;
        }

        protected function getTwig() {
            return $this->twig;
        }

        public function __call($method_name, $args) {
            return $this->get($method_name);
        }
    }
```

Last off we need to mimic the behavior I've posted in the beginning of the question. So lets create a wrapper around the macro template which will be responsible to call the actual functions inside the macro.

As seen the functions inside a macro get prefixed with `macro_`, so just let auto-prefix every call made to the macro wrapper with `macro_`

```
<?php
    class MacroWrapper {
        protected $template = null;

        public function __construct(\Twig\TemplateWrapper $template_wrapper) {
            $this->template = $template_wrapper->unwrap();
        }

        public function __call($method_name, $args){
            return $this->template->{'macro_'.$method_name}(...$args);
        }
    }
```

---

Now inject the extension into `twig`

```
$twig->addExtension(new MacroWrapperExtension());
```

This will enable the function `macro` inside every template, which lets us access any macro file inside the macros folder

```
{{ macro('test').hello('foo') }}

{{ macro('test').bar('foo', 'bar', 'foobar') }}
```

Comment: Good to hear you got it running, I mean there is prolly still room for improving this code, but this seems to be the basic gist